# How to map Claims to SPUser object?

Tags: claims-based-auth, spuser

I have SharePoint 2010 with Claims Authentication (SAML / AD FS v2). I have made an incoming mapping for UPN, Role, CommonName. I want to show the user's "DisplayName" in the right corner (the Name on the profile or PreferredName on SPUser object), but I can't find any solution for how to map the incoming claims to the SPUser object properties.

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to use [SPWeb.EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx). It understands claims.

For example ([from Tyler Holmes](http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2011/03/awkward-usernames-courtesy-of-claims.html)):

```
SPUser spUser = web.EnsureUser(string.Format("i:0#.f|providerName|{0}", fbaUser.UserName));
spUser.Name = "FriendlyName";
spUser.Update();
```